# How to remove info bar when opening a webpage shortcut as a window (Google Chrome Browser)?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-app, address-bar

I use a program called Organizr that runs in the browser and in order to make it easier to use I use the create shortcut option in chrome and check the box to have it open as a window. This is nice because it doesn't have the address bar/tabs/bookmarks bloat from the main browser but the issue is that it has a wide white bar across the top with site information, and it doesn't go away when I make the window fullscreen which is problematic since I use Organizr to access my Plex library and watch videos. Can anyone advise on how to hide/remove this info bar from the window?

[image]

There's the thin bar at the very top that just says Organizr and that is fine, but the bar below it with the (i) and it says Organizr V2 and localhost is what I'm talking about.

(This is a repost from https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8422935?hl=en)

Comment: Can you post the exact shortcut command you use as the Chrome shortcut?

Answer (score 4):

I'm late here and what I'm going to propose here is not even a real solution because it slightly change the window's top bar (at least on edge chromium it becomes white and you can't manage anymore addons and other things):

add this option --app=https://www.yoursitehere.domainhere (replace yoursite.domainhere with the link of the site you want see as app) to the destination (in shortcut property).

If you find any other solution would be awesome

Comment: nice! but how to do it with multiple sites in tabs?

Comment: @johnywhy I'm unsure about your question. Actually neither kiosk mode or app mode supports tabs or multiple sites. You can just open 1 site like an app, if that site obviously is made like a web app (otherwise it can be difficult to navigate). If you just want tabs without address bar you can't: that feature was called "compact mode" and was removed time ago

Comment: @johnywhy what I can think actually is that you could try to install more sites like apps and use an external program like groupy or tidytabs (on windows. For other oses you need to search an alike program). Maybe not an awesome solution but ‍♂️

Comment: here's my solution, but it opens each site in a different window. `cmd.exe /c start "" "chrome.exe" -app=http://google.com && cmd.exe /c start "" "chrome.exe" -app=http://theboom.org`